Intent / Bundle Deprecated Methods
I have a Parcelable data class object I want to pass from one Activity to another via an Intent
intent.putExtra("barcodeListItem", listItem)
Before API level 33, retrieving this class object was no problem until seemingly everything under the sun (function wise) for the Intent class has became deprecated. Like the below line of code.
val listItem = intent.getParcelableExtra<BarcodeListItem>("barcodeListItem")
I've tried everything I can think of, like using a Bundle instead
var bundle = Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("barcodeListItem1",listItem);
intent.putExtras(bundle);

I can get the bundle in the receiving Activity, but can't figure out how to extract the class object. Because similar to Intent, everything I've tried using Bundle to get the class object is also deprecated. The get method ( along with a host of other methods) has become deprecated.
val bundle = intent.extras 
val listObject = bundle?.get("barcodeListItem1")


Did you try IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra() or the non-deprecated form of getParcelableExtra() on Intent?

val listItem = IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(intent,"barcodeListItem", BarcodeListItem::class.java);
That worked

The replacement for getParcelableExtra(String) is getParcelableExtra (String name, Class<T> clazz).  So you just need to call getParcelableExtra("variablename", BarcodeListItem::class.java)

I ended up using IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra()   That got around the deprecation issue I was experiencing
val listItem = IntentCompat.getParcelableExtra(intent,"barcodeListItem", BarcodeListItem::class.java);
